# $select Id in EmployeeId uri query without specifying the propertyname

Tags: odata

I have a odata api with a bunch of classes similar to this:

```
public class Store
{
    [Key]
    public Guid StoreId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }    
}

public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Guid StoreId { get; set; }
    public Store Store { get; set; }

}

public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public Guid EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }    
}
```

and would like to return just the keys of queried entities in an odata uri. 
I'd like to be able to query a Store and get just the id's of all nested entities. a result similar to:

```
"StoreId": "b755d42f-6aa9-4022-bd45-03f9922597f6",
        "Employee": [
            {
                "EmployeeId": "143baded-244e-4e0b-9baf-1acc7062eaa8"
            },
            {
                "EmployeeId": "95daa7e5-bae8-43e3-8a99-ecd8dfbceae6"
            }
```

I'd expect to be able to use a uri like $select=$id to just return the keys on any odata query, but I don't seem to be able to find anything on the subject. 
As the names are by convention 
I have also looked into searching for propertynames and putting the result in the $select param

TLDR: is there a way to $select the id's of an entity in a odata query without literally typing the id property name?